# Is there a way to use trivia/optima for pattern matching FSet or Sycamore?

Tags: pattern-matching, common-lisp

In a functional programming setup with Common Lisp it would be cool to also use trivia for pattern matching on immutable maps of FSet.
But I couldn't make it work and I figure out whether this works or not.

Update: Trivia can now match on FSet data types.

Comment: Did you try using `defpattern` to define custom matchers for FSet data-structures?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently ATM there is no support for FSet matching in trivia.

However, @coredump, indeed it is relatively easy to expand trivia. I got a simple `equal` match already working. Working on more fine grained support for it.